# Embedding vue app within server-side framework app. Vue Public Path fails

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

TLDR - Embedding a vue app in a Phoenix app. Building the vue app with vue cli and making sure the files go into the directories they are supposed to within the Pheonix project. When built, the app doesn't work as the asset file path does not match the `publicPath`.

I build my vue app to `../../lib/exampleapp_web/templates/page`. I need to use a custom html template to remove vues `<html>`,`<head>`, and `<body>` tags, as Pheonix renders this page template within an existing layout template.

my vue.config.js looks like this

`vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  outputDir: '../../lib/exampleapp_web/templates/page',
  assetsDir: '../../../../assets/static',
  indexPath: 'index.html.eex',
  publicPath: './', // should make asset routes relative to route
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugin('html').tap(args => {
      return [{
        template: "./public/index.html", // custom vue html template
        minify: false, // so I can read it
        inject: false // so html, head, body etc isn't injected
      }]
    })
  }
}
```

When built, the rendered asset paths are wrong (renders the assetDir, not the path specified in publicPath):

`<script src="../../../../assets/static/js/chunk-vendors.74d8847d.js"></script>`

When I need: `<script src="./js/chunk-vendors.74d8847d.js"></script>`

So to correct this, I am doing a string replace within my vue html template:

`public/index.html`

```
<!-- https://github.com/jaketrent/html-webpack-template/blob/86f285d5c790a6c15263f5cc50fd666d51f974fd/index.html -->

    <% for (var css in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css) { %>
        <link href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css[css].replace('./../../../assets/static/','/') %>" rel="stylesheet">
        <% } %>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <% for (var chunk in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks) { %>
        <script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[chunk].entry.replace('./../../../assets/static/','/') %>"></script>
        <% } %>
```

This renders:

```
    <link href="./css/chunk-vendors.257c6d34.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="./css/app.d5864d1f.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="./js/chunk-vendors.74d8847d.js"></script>

    <script src="./js/app.b25a73d8.js"></script>
```

This works.... it just feels clunky. Having to edit the template each time to replace paths isn't really viable. Is there a better way?

I thought the publicPath option would do it https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath - its just not working for me.

`By default, Vue CLI assumes your app will be deployed at the root of a domain, e.g. https://www.my-app.com/. If your app is deployed at a sub-path, you will need to specify that sub-path using this option. For example, if your app is deployed at https://www.foobar.com/my-app/, set publicPath to '/my-app/'`

Answer (score 0):

Found a better solution - disable the HTML generation... its a static file, so make it a template file within the backend app. Build the JS and CSS - specify the asset file names, and have them output to your chosen folder. Most of this config was found in a blog post - however, I can't remember which one...

vue.config.js

```
const assetsDir = './../../../assets/static'
// This config disables HTML, and builds static assets
// static assets are stuck in assetsDir.
// assetsDir does NOT filter down - hence we have to add it to each filename
// We give each file a name - this breaks cachebusting (if you use it)
// We create a static html file - which loads our paths
module.exports = {
  assetsDir,
  configureWebpack: {
    output: {
      filename: assetsDir + "/js/my-file.js",
      chunkFilename: assetsDir + "/js/my-file-chunk.js"
    }
  },

  chainWebpack: config => {
    if (config.plugins.has("extract-css")) {
      const extractCSSPlugin = config.plugin("extract-css");
      extractCSSPlugin &&
      extractCSSPlugin.tap(() => [
        {
          filename: assetsDir + "/css/my-file.css",
          chunkFilename: assetsDir + "/css/my-file-chunk.css"
        }
      ]);
    }

    config.plugins
      .delete("html")
      .delete("prefetch")
      .delete("preload");
  }
}
```

Benefit of this is - at build, your files get dumped into the correct directory. You don't have to faff about with building html templates, as you just build your server-side template as you normally would. This applies to any integration - not just Phoenix.